# Compass ignoring tint and shade functions in SCSS file

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have an issue when compiling a few SCSS files using compass. Basically the `tint` and `shade` functions are being ignored. So, this:

```
border:solid 1px tint( $custom-ui-base-color, 5% );
background-color:shade( $custom-ui-base-color, 15% );
```

becomes this:

```
border: solid 1px tint(#096fcb, 5%);
background-color: shade(#096fcb, 15%);
```

Which obviously isn't valid CSS. Compass has replaced the variables but not calculated the functions, is there any reason why this might be the case? A setting or command line argument in compass maybe?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is late, but I had the same problem until I found out that I can just use the `mix()` function. Maybe this will be helpful to other people. `mix()` can tint your existing color with any color you want. So to tint it white(which seems to be what you wanted), you just do it like this:

`$color: mix(white,$color, 15%);`

the first argument is the color you want your main color tinted with, second argument is your color and third argument is the amount of color(white in this case) you want to be mixed in with your main color.

So in my case, i mixed in 15% white.

Comment: Note that this question specifies Compass (which provides tint and shade functions).  If you're not using Compass (or another library that defines them), then of course you don't have these functions available.

Comment: I had the problem even with compass when defining a variable: `$something: tint($color, 15%)` and using this in another function: `background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $something 0%, $something 100%);`, my `$something` was replaced exactly with `tint(...)` and not evaluated in output. Using `tint` directly and not as a variable worked though. Replacing it with `mix` in the variable solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I dig some digging and it seems like [these functions were added to Compass core about a year ago](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/pull/917), though I didn't dig further into the changelogs to see which version they made it into.

Tint and Shade are not built-in SASS color functions. The [Compass documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) makes reference to them, but [the corresponding SASS docs do not](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html). So they must be an add-on for Compass, and might be accessible as an additional library extension.

[Net Magazine's examples](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/colour-theming-sass-and-compass) makes it seem as though you are using them correctly. So, I'm not sure where to point you, but you can try to debug the functions a bit more to see if you can get them to compile. Try using `shade( #{$custom-ui-base-color}, 15% )` for a start, which should force Compass to do one calculation before the other (in this case, simply compiling the variable).

Ruby documentation of the functions: http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/c/compass-0.12.2/Compass/SassExtensions/Functions/Colors.html

Good luck!